# Specifying pathname in map_dfr

Tags: r, dplyr

The structure of my directory is as follows:

```
Extant_Data -> Data -> Raw 
                            -> course_enrollment
                            -> frpm
```

I have a few different function to to read in some text files and excel files respectively.

```
read_fun = function(path){
  test = read.delim(path, sep="\t", header=TRUE, fill = TRUE, colClasses = c(rep("character",23)))
  test
}


read_fun_frpm= function(path){
  test = read_excel(path, sheet = 2, col_names = frpm_names)
}
```

I feed this into map_dfr so that the function reads in each of the files and rowbinds them.

```
allfiles = list.files(path = "Extant_Data/Data/Raw/course_enrollment",
                      pattern = "CourseEnrollment.txt",
                      full.names=FALSE,
                      recursive = T)
# Rowbind all the course enrollment data
# !!! BUT I HAVE set the working directory to a subdirectory so that it finds those files 
setwd("/Extant_Data/Data/Raw/course_enrollment")
course_combined <- map_dfr(allfiles,read_fun)



allfiles = list.files(path = "Extant_Data/Data/Raw/frpm/post12",
                      pattern = "frpm*",
                      full.names=FALSE,
                      recursive = T)
# Rowbind all the course enrollment data
# !!!I have to change the directory AGAIN 
setwd(""Extant_Data/Data/Raw/frpm/post12")
frpm_combined <- map_dfr(allfiles,read_fun_frpm)
```

As mentioned in the comments, I have to keep changing the working directory so that map_dfr can locate the files. I don't think this is best practice, how might I work around this so I don't have to keep changing the directory? Any suggestions appreciated. Sorry it's hard to provide a re-producible example.

Note: This throws an error.

```
frpm_combined <- map_dfr(allfiles,read_fun_frpm('Extant_Data/Data/Raw/frpm/post12'))
```

Comment: I may be mistaking the issue on my quick skim of your question, but can't you get the full file paths with `full.names = TRUE`?

Comment: @aosmith Can't believe I did not think of that. Thank you!